# Clicking run configurations not working for the java file I click on is my eclipse bugged or is this a simple fix?

Tags: eclipse

[image: I click the java file]Every time I right click on a java file to use the run configuration it won't open for that specific file I'm clicking on but the one I previously did. It will do the same for the button on the menu bar at top. I also noticed that it will only allow me to right click and use run configuration on the one I want only until after I run the program and get a run time error. I've tried to restart eclipse but it does the same thing still. So is this a bug on eclipses part or is it a preference option that can be changed?
Currently using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - 2021-06

[image: It shows the gridpane is selected as I click run configurations]

[image: BUT SHOWBOX is what opens when]

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on what object you are right-clicking on, and its characteristics.  If Eclipse doesn't see a "main" method, it won't allow running it as a Java Application.

In any case, you've provided very little information here.  For instance, we have no idea what "it won't open" means.

Comment: I mean the run configuration menu. I had a bunch of java files that I was asked to paste into a src folder and then configure them for use of java fx.  I'm in the processing of setting the vm arguments of all the java files that got pasted into eclipse but when I right click a java file/or click on the run configurations option on say ball.java it will open the run configuration menu but it's not for ball.java instead it opens for dog.java

Comment: It also does the same thing if I have two working java programs I'll call txt.java and button.java if I run specifically txt.jav it will run button.java instead and wont actually run txt.java unless I close all my open files and restart eclipse

Comment: You're going to have to be specific about exactly what you are doing, and exactly what is happening.

Comment: Ok, you're now showing some pictures, which helps. I can't see the entire contents of the "Run As" menu.  I would guess the first choice is "Java Application", and the second is "Run Configurations".  Have you ever selected "Java Application" and run the class? In the Run Configurations list, do you actually have a run configuration corresponding to "ShowGridPane"?

Comment: Yes the first choice is java application and the second is run configuration. The problem is when I click run configuration it does not pull up the file I'm currently working with but the previous one. I'm trying to find out if this is a bug of eclipse

Comment: I asked multiple questions in my last comment, and you didn't answer any of them.